# Web page marker/annotator/highlighter

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Could someone suggest a tool that I can use to achieve the following:

[image]

Basically, I need to enclose the text of interest with a rectangle and write a label in the neighborhood.

I'm not sure what we should call such kind of tools. I tried the keywords in the title but failed to find an appropriate extension or add-on for browsers, which is preferred. Other tools that's simple enough to use will do too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some screenshot tools have that functionality; such as [**Awesome Screenshot**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce?hl=en) Chrome extension.
[image]

The keywords here may be "Screenshot" and "Annotator".

Comment: By the way, can we use this tool to annotate and capture a drop down menu in web page?

Comment: I'm not the author. To capture a dropdown menu you can use the Key shortcut: `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `v`.